# Liferay Document Library: Manual versioning

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

we are setting up multiple sites e.g A, B, we need to sync content of Site A on Site B, but, there probably is some problem with the site A due to which a difference of the version occurs, though the content does get synchronized with the site B.I want to make my sync component independent that can deal with the version mismatch.is there any possibility in liferay through which we can give manual version number/name?

Many Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what "sync content of site A on site B" means. You can (and should) keep the content in one site. That doesn't limit you from linking, e.g. embedding images from one site in another one - at the end it's only URLs on the UI. Or are you inventing your own staging scheme?

Comment: its actually two physical repositories on single tenant, Two physical sites i want to sync them as same level though i did most of the part.
when i create content on Site A sometimes it made two version (1.0 Draft), (2.0, Approved) our sync tool get Approved one and add on Site B with version(1.0) though content sync successfully with different version no
I want it to be same as on Site A (2.0 approved)

Comment: Oh, look: Another unlinked crosspost https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/66943281. Thanks for generating duplicate work and leaving both ends decoupled from each other...

Comment: i am sorry, is it bad practice to push issue on different forums, to get more views about it?

I think i wasn't able to deliver my question.

Comment: If you're not linking your multiple posts, you're generating duplicate work. Nobody here knows if the question has long been answered elsewhere (and vice versa). That's quite disrespectful towards those that you expect to help you for free. More detail here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: Thanks Olaf for valuable information. I will take care of it from now on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. However, I'd store every document only once and reference it from A and B. You can site it in global scope, which is automatically shared, create a site hierarchy and share or just create a site C and refer to it.

Don't duplicate data if it literally just doubles the size of backups